# Bad sectors on HDD

Tags: hard-drive

Assessment disk is OK. There are 64 bad sectors. This value 64 remains the same and doesn't go up. Should I replace the HDD? My laptop is still under warranty. I tried to repair the file system and the result is OK; no errors.

Data from Smart:

- Reallocated sector count value 64 sectors ok
- Uncorrectable sector count value 0 sectors ok
- Current pending sector count value 0 sectors ok

Comment: If still in warranty I would ask for an HDD replacement.

Comment: It's not unusual for a HDD to be manufactured with a few bad sectors.  A laptop still in warranty with 64 bad sectors is abnormally high.  The assessment of OK is because the drive still has enough spares to handle it.  But it would be high even on a very old drive.  The drive has a problem if it has that many bad sectors; it isn't normal manufacturing quality or normal wear.  Yeah, ask for a warranty replacement of the drive.